# How can I make words starting with # or @ string act like UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uilabel, instagram

For example, A `UILabel` has `@asdf when did you come?`. Now I want to make `@asdf` act like a UIButton. So that it locates in `UILabel`, but its color is not default and can react when I touch it. How could it be implemented?

Comment: Can't you simply make a UIButton with the text @asdf that is on top of part of the rest of the UILabel message in Interface Builder?

Comment: It could be clearer in the question, but I believe he wants substrings matching a certain pattern to act like links, though the "link" would trigger an action in his app.  [#21 here looks useful](http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#textViewLinks).  Even mentions Twitter as well.

Comment: If the above is the case, You can use `TTTAttributedLabel`, to which you should pass the attributed string and the link to which it should connect. 

Even @stevesliva's answer also looks useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRegularExpression) to locate the substrings you would like to have at as links. That will give you a set of [`NSTextCheckingResult`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTextCheckingResult) objects which identify the range of each matching substring.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#\S+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSAssert(error == nil, @"Regular expression was not valid");
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
```

You can then construct an attributed string which decorates those ranges with links.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:input];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *hashTag = [input substringWithRange:result.range];
    NSString *linkContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"app-custom-scheme://hashtag?tag=%@", hashTag, nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:linkContent];
    [attributedString addAttributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName : url} range:result.range];
}];
```

This attributed string can then be set as the `attributedText` of a `UITextView` and the `UITextViewDelegate` method [`-textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:) will be called when a link is tapped. Now you just need to react to those delegate method calls, or to your app opening URLs of a certain pattern, with whatever behavior you want to attach to those generated links.

Comment: `#\S+` make warning. Use `#\\S+`. Thanks.